# How do I disable the debug close application dialogue on Windows XP?

Tags: testing, windows-xp

I  get the debug close dialogue (foo.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.) during an automated test run. I would like to disable this so my application dies silently (or with command line message).

The nearest to a solution I have found is:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;188296
This disables the debug button on that dialogue but I still get the dialogue with a close button.

I have also tried the solution from [How do I disable the 'Debug / Close Application' dialog on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/how-do-i-disable-the-debug-close-application-dialog-on-windows-vista) which does not work on Windows XP.

Comment: The dialog will not exist on machines that do not have visual studio installed.

Comment: Thanks. I have the Windows SDK installed so I guess the same goes for that. The machine is also my build machine so I need the the SDK or visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same scenario (automated testing on Windows XP).  The following fixed the problem on our machines:

1. Open regedit and go to the following key:
    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug`
2. Change **Auto** to "1".
3. Change **Debugger** to an empty string (do NOT delete **Debugger**).