# how to prevent the Application Error MessageBox show in Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I need to execute a console application periodly in windows XP. So I use the following python code:

```
import subprocess
import time
while True:
    subprocess.call("test.exe")
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

the problem is that test.exe crashs occasionally, and an error report messagebox pops-up, unless I close the messagebox manually, the python program will be paused at subprocess.call().

After some search, I disabled the error report messagebox as the following link:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/disable-those-annoying-x-application-has-encountered-a-problem-and-must-be-shut-down-messages-in-windows-xp/

the error report messagebox gone, but another application error messagebox pops-up (sorry the messagebox is in Japanese):

[image]

it will also cause the python program pause. I just want the test.exe crashes silently, and let the python program calls it again in next period. How can I prevent the Application Error messagebox shows up?

I can't fix the bugs in test.exe, because I have not source code of it.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/how-do-i-disable-the-debug-close-application-dialog-on-windows-vista

Comment: @jschorr: It seems that the solution is for windows vista. I searched "Windows Error Reporting" in my Registry, and found nothing. I also created the entries manually, but the messagebox remained. I also deleted the AeDebug\Debugger entries, the messagebox poped-up without the cancel button.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was for xp

Comment: @eryksun : thank you, finally I use autoit3 to close the messagebox.