# Why subprocess can't successfully kill the old running process?

Tags: python, subprocess, kill, terminate

I run a program `test.py`.
Since it collapses frequently, I import `subprocess` to restart it when it stops.
Sometimes I found subprocess can't successfully restart it.
Hence, I force the program to restart every 60 minutes.
But I find that there sometimes two test.py processing running simutanously.
What's wrong with my code and how to fix it?
I use windows 7 OS.
Plz check the following codes and thanks in advance:

```
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime

p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', r'D:\test.py'], shell=True)
minutes = 1
total_time = 0
while True:
    now = datetime.now()

    #periodly restart
    total_time += 1
    if total_time % 100 == 0:
        try:
            p.kill()
        except Exception as e:
            terminated = True
        finally:
            p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', r'D:\test.py'], shell=True)

    #check and restart if it stops
    try:
        terminated = p.poll()
    except Exception as e:
        terminated = True
    if terminated:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', r'D:\test.py'], shell=True)
    time.sleep(minutes * 60)
```

Comment: drop `shell=True` -- it creates unnecessary here `cmd.exe` process (`p.kill()` kills that process).

Comment: related: [subprocess can't successfully restart the targeted python file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28302081/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't agree at all with your design, the specific problem is here:

```
except Exception as e:
        terminated = True
finally:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', r'D:\test.py'], shell=True)
```

In the case that an `Exception` was thrown, you're setting `terminated` to `true`, but then immediately restarting the subprocess. Then, later, you check:

```
if terminated:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', r'D:\test.py'], shell=True)
```

At this point, `terminated` is `true`, so it starts a new subprocess. However, it already had done that in the `finally` block.

Really, what you should do is simply not bother restarting it during the kill attempt:

```
    try:
        p.kill()
    except Exception:
        # We don't care, just means it was already dead
        pass
    finally:
        # Either the process is dead, or we just killed it. Either way, need to restart
        terminated = True
```

Then your `if terminated` clause will properly restart the process and you won't have a duplicate.

Comment: Can't agree with you more. Thanks so much.

Comment: Your mentioned that "At this point, terminated is true, so it starts a new subprocess. ". But since I restart it in the 'finally' clause, should 'terminated==None' in the following 'try' clause? Do you mean that the period is too short to let the program run again such that at that point 'terminated==True'?

Comment: You aren't restarting the script making those calls, you're restarting its child process, `p`. Anyway, The second `try` block has no bearing on the evaluation of the `if terminated` statement, that is always checked every iteration of the `while` loop.