# Throwin std::exception causes VS 2013 unit testing module crash

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I've created unit test project for my C++ application in Visual Studio 2013. Unfortunately, it does not correctly handles exceptions during test: If i run test that just does following:

```
throw std::runtime_exception("hello!");
```

I see Windows "application has stopped working" box telling me that `vstest.executionengine.exe` has crashed. Meanwhile, **Test Explorer** in visual studio shows that this test has passed without errors.

Visual studio itself reports that "active test" was aborted, and error is unexpected. Reffers to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx but there is absolutely no useful information on that page about my problem.

How to properly terminate test execution in C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/how-do-i-disable-the-debug-close-application-dialog-on-windows-vista does not help, it still says that test has passed in 1 sec. Debugging test code after exception is thrown shows that it attempts to read memory at 08h before crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

- Ensure that all your tests can run at one time, because that's how unit tests work in VS2013 (Run All i mean)
- Ensure that you have no *assert(..)* calls, use `Assert` class provided by header `CppUnitTestAssert.h`
- Try removing I/O from your test code, for example, try using `Logger` class provided by header `CppUnitTestLogger.h` instead of your own implementation
- Use command *TESTS > Debug > Debug all tests* to run all tests in debug mode, you will *definetely* find reason of your crashes.

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694604.aspx)

**Reason of crashes**

I think it is how assertion worked in my code, maybe it's `abort()`. This caused something unexpected in hosting process.