# How to catch Windows Application crash window?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pywinauto

When I run `pywinauto` test of my application I got some error and Windows Apllication crash window are showed. But `pywinauto` not raise TimeoutError or ElementNotFoundError, nothing, just waiting. And I don't know how to handle this situation.
[image: Window crash dialog]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the 'Debug / Close Application' dialog on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/how-do-i-disable-the-debug-close-application-dialog-on-windows-vista)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I don't want to disable this window. I want to handle and show error in my tests.

Comment: Do you have some piece of code or at least screenshots?

Comment: Do you mean standard Windows crash dialog? Or do you use crash handler component like CrashRpt? Maybe CrashRpt is just what you need?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, yes, standart Windows crash dialog.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Need some time to reproduce it on my side because there are no details like screenshots and code attempts. Also helping my students to finish new high level features for pywinauto.

Comment: I decided to postpone this task for now. But I will be glad to help.