# How to just close a program when it crashes, without any warning screens, etc ... C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, juce

I'm doing a Windows program with JUCE and C++, and I want it to just close when it crashes. Right now it shows the crash dialog and you have to hit close. I don't want to show anything, just to close it. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Look into `std::signal`, and `std::set_terminate`.

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369

Comment: It seems like a better idea would be to fix whatever it is that's caushing your program to crash, then you'll never see the dialog.

Comment: Thanks guys!! The program is a plugin scanner, so it checks 3rd party files that may crash, so is out of my control. ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/467652/126995

Answer (score 1):

Found what I needed, and it works perfectly.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <rtcapi.h>
int exception_handler(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS p)
{
    printf("Exception detected during the unit tests!\n");
    exit(1);
}
int runtime_check_handler(int errorType, const char *filename, int linenumber, const char *moduleName, const char *format, ...)
{
    printf("Error type %d at %s line %d in %s", errorType, filename, linenumber, moduleName);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    DWORD dwMode = SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
    SetErrorMode(dwMode | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter((LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER)&exception_handler); 
    _RTC_SetErrorFunc(&runtime_check_handler);

    // Run your tests here

    return 0;
}
```